# Python web scraping login

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to login to a website using python.
The login URL is :

`https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=pwfone:login`

and the 'form action' url is shown as :

```
https://login.flash.co.za/apex/wwv_flow.accept
```

When I use the ' inspect element' on chrome when logging in manually, these are the form posts that show up (pt_02 = password):

[image]

There a few hidden items that I'm not sure how to add into the python code below.

When I use this code, the login page is returned:

```
import requests
url = 'https://login.flash.co.za/apex/wwv_flow.accept'
values =    {'p_flow_id': '1500',
            'p_flow_step_id': '101',
            'p_page_submission_id': '3169092211412',
            'p_request': 'LOGIN',
            'p_t01': 'solar',
            'p_t02': 'password',
             'p_checksum': ''
            }

r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print r.content
```

How can I adjust this code to perform a login?

Chrome network:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more or less your script should look like. Use session to handle the cookies automatically. Fill in the `username` and `password` fields manually.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

logurl = "https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=pwfone:login"
posturl = 'https://login.flash.co.za/apex/wwv_flow.accept'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.get(logurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    values = {
        'p_flow_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_flow_id']")['value'],
        'p_flow_step_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_flow_step_id']")['value'],
        'p_instance': soup.select_one("[name='p_instance']")['value'],
        'p_page_submission_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_page_submission_id']")['value'],
        'p_request': 'LOGIN',
        'p_arg_names': soup.select_one("[name='p_arg_names']")['value'],
        'p_t01': 'username',
        'p_arg_names': soup.select_one("[name='p_arg_names']")['value'],
        'p_t02': 'password',
        'p_md5_checksum': soup.select_one("[name='p_md5_checksum']")['value'],
        'p_page_checksum': soup.select_one("[name='p_page_checksum']")['value']
    }

    r = s.post(posturl, data=values)
    print r.content
```

Comment: I can see that. My question is, the only user input is p_t01 and p_t02 (username and password). What values do I use for the rest in the python script? It seems some of them change for each login...

Comment: ..but these change for every login? How do I preempt what they will be?

Comment: Let me try to make you a script then.

Comment: Yes, please. I have added the chrome network Headers, if that helps.

Comment: Made a minor change. Check out the edit @wazzahenry.

Comment: Thanks! -  I'm getting this - `FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?` I'm guessing I need to pip install something here?

Comment: use `html.parser` instead. Like this `BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")`.

Comment: One last thing: make sure `LOGIN`, `username` and `password` are wrapped witin quotes. I have already edited the script to reflect the changes.

Comment: I have done the above. It is returning a message to say that my password is not correct, even though it has been correctly inserted in the code. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the `logurl` maybe incorrect, should it not be the `location` listed in the image added, ie: `https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=1500:1:4429729965554` ?.. being the url that is actually being pulled down? the current logurl is the page where one enters username and password.

Answer (score 0):

since I cannot recreate your case I can't tell you what exactly to change, but when I was doing such things I used [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to intercept all requests my browser sends. So I'd install that, along with browser extension and then perform login. Then you can view the request in Postman, also view the response it received there, what's more it provides you with Python code of request too, so you could simply copy and use it then.
Shortly, use Pstman, perform login, clone their request.