# Problems logging into a site with requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to login into a website with requests. 
This website is from the Central Bank of Brasil.

My issue is that the login box has come different from the tutorials I've found till now.

Instead of just one box, I have the options of login with "Usuário SISBACEN" box or "CPF" box (this last one, CPF, is the one I have the access).

How can I make a code to log in this site and get the data?

I tried this one, but I had not success. It is returning an error like I've forgot to give all the four information from the Usuário SISBACEN box, but I tried to login by CPF box:

```
    #the page I want to try the login
    logurl = "https://bccorreio.bcb.gov.br/bccorreio/Autenticacao/Logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fbccorreio%2f"

    #the page I want to requests information from.
    posturl = "https://bccorreio.bcb.gov.br/bccorreio/Consultas/Normativos/PesquisaNormativos.aspx?tipoConsulta=C"

    with requests.session() as s:
        s.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
        res = s.get(logurl)

        soup = bs(res.text, "lxml")

        values = {
            "__LASTFOCUS": soup.select_one("[name='__LASTFOCUS']")['value'],
            "__EVENTTARGET": soup.select_one("[name='__EVENTTARGET']")['value'],
            "__EVENTARGUMENT": soup.select_one("[name='__EVENTARGUMENT']")['value'],
            "__VIEWSTATE": soup.select_one("[name='__VIEWSTATE']")['value'],
            "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": soup.select_one("[name='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR']")['value'],
            "lgLogin$rbTipoLogin": "1",
            "lgLogin$UserName": xxxxxx,
            "lgLogin$Password": xxxxx,
            "lgLogin$Login": "Entrar"
        }

        r = s.post(posturl, data=values)
        print(r.text)
```

Does anyone can explain me what am I doing wrong? I think is something with this "CPF" box, witch I think i'm not properly selecting.

Hope you can help me even with no access to this website.

OBS: Python 3.6
macOS high Sierra

[image: My post requests when I log manually - I deleted log and password from the image]

Comment: There are around eleven fields (inputname with values; most of the values generate automatically) to pass as a payload in your post request to get a valid response/to get logged in. I can see only two in your script and that's the reason it is not working.

Comment: But how can I write the code to make this field values generate automatically?

Comment: [Check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852786/python-web-scraping-login) to get an idea to proceed.

Comment: I tried to update the code as the model you provided. But I still not got the response. Sorry to disturb you, but could you take another look at it?

Comment: In your case the eparameters are slightly different. Your payload should look like: [click the link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0udggzu2u0pdm3/login%20payload.txt?dl=0).

Comment: Kick out the word `firstinputbox` and place there what you write in the firstinputbox in that site before logging in and so on.

Comment: I update it with the image from the manual login... maybe it will help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173808/discussion-between-cristian-favaro-carrico-and-sim).

Comment: Yeah! It worked!
I changed the form. I put the letters and numbers manually for all and looks like it worked. 
Thanks, man (or girl)!

Comment: Glad it worked.

Comment: How could you log in impungs me because `https://bccorreio.bcb.gov.br/bccorreio/Autenticacao/Logon.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fbccorreio%2f` should be your `posturl` as well. However, you used different url in this line `r = s.post(posturl, data=values)` that is where i doubt.

Comment: Try makiing `get` and `post` request with the same `logurl` (I repeat, not `posturl`) and see what happens.